# Recursive query in Oracle 9

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle9i

I would like to write a query to compute the degrees of separation between someone and his friends. I wrote the following:

```
WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT UserFriends.PlayerID AS PlayerID, UserFriends.FriendsWith AS Friend, 
                   1 AS Distance 
            FROM UserFriends WHERE UserFriends.PlayerID = 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT CTE.PlayerID, UserFriends.FriendsWith AS Friend, 
                   CTE.Distance + 1 AS Distance 
            FROM UserFriends 
            INNER JOIN CTE ON UserFriends.PlayerID = CTE.Friend
) 
SELECT PlayerID, Friend, Distance FROM CTE;
```

But I get an error message:

```
Error: ORA-32031: illegal reference of a query name in WITH clause
```

It seems that this type of recursive query was only introduced in version 11g R2. If so, how can I achieve the same result with version 9.2?

Edit:

I have re-written the query as follows:

```
INSERT INTO Degrees_Separation
   SELECT PlayerID, FriendsWith, LEVEL AS Degree
      FROM UserFriends
      START WITH PlayerID = 1
      CONNECT BY FriendsWith = PRIOR PlayerID
      AND LEVEL <= 10
      AND PRIOR DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE != DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE;

SELECT DISTINCT * FROM Degrees_Separation
WHERE PlayerID = 1;
```

Here is the content of UserFriends:

```
PLAYERID    FRIENDSWITH
1   2
1   3
1   8
1   12
2   1
2   4
2   7
2   9
2   15
```

The result is not what I expected. For PlayerID = 1, I only see records where the FriendsWith is 2, 3, 8 and 12, i.e. the immediate friends of PlayerID 1

```
PLAYERID    FRIENDSWITH DEGREE
1   2   1
1   2   3
1   2   5
1   2   6
1   2   7
1   2   8
1   2   9
1   2   10
1   3   1
1   3   3
1   3   5
1   3   6
1   3   7
1   3   8
1   3   9
1   3   10
1   8   1
1   8   3
1   8   5
1   8   7
1   8   8
1   8   9
1   8   10
1   12  1
1   12  3
1   12  5
1   12  6
1   12  7
1   12  8
1   12  9
1   12  10
```

Comment: There is a keyword `connect by (prior)`. Look for documentation on it.

Comment: I've voted to close as a duplicate. It's almost identical, save that it restricts to a degree of separation rather than attempting to find it. There's also information available in the [9i documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10500_01/server.920/a96540/queries4a.htm). P.S. 9i has been out of extended support for a while... it might be worth updating.